# TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am a novice MERN stack developer.
I am trying to calculate the number of pages for pagination. The info object prints in `console.log`. However, when I try to use it in the for loop I get an error.

Can someone please explain what's the React logic or flow behind this? I have had issues with this multiple times but, could fix it with conditional rendering. But, somehow I wasn't able to fix this and I don't seem to understand the logic of how the flow in react is.

```
App Component :
    const App = () => {
      const [episodes, setEpisodes] = useState({});
      const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
      const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
      const [episodesPerPage, setEpisodesPerPage] = useState(10);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const fetchEpisodes = async () => {
          setLoading(true);
          const res = await axios.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/');
          setEpisodes(res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        };
        fetchEpisodes();
      }, []);
      console.log(episodes.info);
      return (
        <div>
          <div id='header'>
            <h1>Rick & Morty</h1>
            <h2>Episodes</h2>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>All Episodes</h3>
            <EpisodeList episodeList={episodes.results} loading={loading} />
            <Pagenation info={episodes.info} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;

    Pagenation Component:
    
    const Pagenation = ({ info }) => {
      const pageNumbers = [];
        console.log(info);
      for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(info.count / 20); i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
      }
      return (
        <nav aria-label='...'>
          <ul class='pagination pagination-lg'>
            {pageNumbers.map((number) => {
              return (
                <li class='page-item active' aria-current='page'>
                  <span class='page-link'>
                    {number}
                    <span class='sr-only'>(current)</span>
                  </span>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      );
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional rendering can be the solution here as well.

`episodes` is initially an empty object, so `episodes.info` is initially `undefined`. This means you cannot access a property on `info` without checking if it exists first because you know already that it will be `undefined` at the beginning.

A simple solution might look like this:

```js
{episodes.info && <Pagenation info={episodes.info} />}
```

You could also move the conditional into the `Pagenation` component to be something like this:

```js
if (info) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(info.count / 20); i++) {
    pageNumbers.push(i);
  }
}
```

Regardless of your strategy to avoid the error, the core of the issue is that you have data that is loaded after the component mounts. This means you need to account for that data being missing for at least one render.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to explain the concept. it worked !